# Testing enque of nested worker from another sidekiq worker

Tags: rspec, sidekiq, rspec-sidekiq

We have two workers as demonstrated below :

```rb
class WorkerOne
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(arg_1, arg_2)
    # some calculation figure out arg_3
    WorkerTwo.perform_async(arg_3, arg_2)
  end
end

class WorkerTwo
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(arg_3, arg_2)
    # some heavy lifting
  end
end
```

We need to test that when `WorkerOne` is executed, `WorkerTwo` is also enqueued?
We tried using `Sidekiq::Testing.inline!` to execute `WorkerOne.perform_async(arg_1, arg_2)`
As `WorkerTwo.perform_async(arg_3, arg_2)` is executed from inside WorkerOne, we tried testing the `WorkerTwo.jobs` array length to change from `0` to `1`, assuming the job was enqueued from within `WorkerOne`, but it doesnot change.
We used the below expectation in our test example:

```
expect{WorkerOne.perform_async(task.id, user.id)}.to change(WorkerTwo.jobs, :size).by(1)
```

got the below error

```
 expected `Array#size` to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

Please help with any suggestions and feedbacks on the approach used.

Answer (score 2):

Sidekiq workers can be directly invoked using `Worker.new.perform` which ensures they run in inline mode - simple Ruby method invocation. Not the prettiest solution but comes in handy for testing.

```
  expect {
    WorkerOne.new.perform(10, 15)
  }.to change(WorkerTwo.jobs, :size).by(1)
```

Here's an executable gist - https://gist.github.com/tejasbubane/09c1412b88ce1e9cb3dacff0817119d2